# Finding difference of values in vector in c++

Tags: c++

I have to write a program that reads in 15 prices and stores them in a sequential container and then sorts them into increasing order. The program then should find and display: The trading range(the lowest and highest prices) .. and A sequence that shows how much the price rose and fell each day.
I am having problems with creating the sequence to show how much the price rose and fell. I'm trying to use `adjacent_difference` but I receive "Segmentation fault" errors when I run it. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
 int i;
 int s=15;
 int p;
 vector <int> prices;
 vector <int> dif;

  cout<<"Please enter the trading price: ";
  while(prices.size()<s && cin>>p)
    prices.push_back(p);
  cout<<"The differences in price: "<<adjacent_difference(prices.begin(),prices.end(),dif.begin())<<endl;
  sort(prices.begin(),prices.end());
  cout<<"The smallest number is "<<*min_element(prices.begin(),prices.end())<<endl;
  cout<<"The latgest number is "<<*max_element(prices.begin(),prices.end())<<endl;


return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the compile error?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/numeric/adjacent_difference/

- adjacent_difference requires an **output iterator** as its third parameter.
- it **returns an iterator**

So you'll be wanting to do something like:

```
auto dif_iter = adjacent_difference(prices.begin(),prices.end(),back_inserter(dif));
```

And then dif will be filled with the difference, and iter will be an iterator to where the differences begin.

By the sounds of it you'll want to iterate over all the differences to show the price change each day. So you'll be wanting to put that in a loop:

```
for( auto iter = dif_iter; iter != dif.end(); ++iter )
{
  cout << ... some information with *iter ...
}
```

Comment: ITYM `back_inserter(dif)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no `operator<<` function can insert the return value of `adjacent_differenc` to `std::cout`.

Did you mean

```
cout<<"The differences in price: " << *adjacent_difference(prices.begin(),prices.end(),dif.begin())<<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::adjacent_difference` requires an `OutputIterator` as its third argument:

```
adjacent_difference( prices.begin(), prices.end(), back_inserter(dif) );
```

You will need `#include <iterator>` for this.

It returns the same `OutputIterator`. You cannot use an OutputIterator to retrieve the values. Instead, what you want to do is print out all the entries in `dif`:

```
cout << "The differences in price: ";
for (int x : dif)
    cout << x << " ";
cout << endl;
```

Moving on, the `min_element` and `max_element` function go through the vector looking for those elements. It's redundant to also sort the vector. You should just do one of these two options:

- `sort()` and then output the first and last elements
- don't sort, and use `*min_element` and `*max_element`